# Oracle SQL substr/instr solution required

Tags: oracle, substr

I need help with an SQL statement I am trying to run, I have done quite a bit of reading and testing but I cannot get the correct results hence my request here.

I am trying to extract data from a column that has had data concatenated from two sources, I want to seperate the data before & after the join, the join is a ' - ' (hyphen with a space either side), there can be alphanumeric chars before or after that ' - ' and this is the data I need. Just to add to the complexity some rows do not have joined data, i.e. there is no ' - ' and when this is met it is ok to simply extract the whole column value and treat it as the BB side (see first BB example below).

So when I have finished I would like to have seperated out the AA side (before the -) and the BB side (after the -) allowing for the single BB situation.

Looking at the data the following scenarious can occur.

```
BB<br>
AA - BB<br>
AA-aa - BB<br>
AA - BB-bb-cc<br>
AA-aa - BB-bb-cc<br>
```

I can get code to work but not consistently for all of the above scenarious - can you suggest the right code or even if there is a better solution which does not impact SQL performance.

Examples I have been trying for AA side:-

WORKS:

```
select substr('AA - BB-bb', 0, instr('AA - BB-bb', ' - ', 1, 1)-1) AS A_NAME 
from DUAL;
```

FAILS (Only gets AA, not AA-aa):

```
select substr('AA-aa - BB-bb', 0,instr('AA-aa - BB-bb', ' - ', 1, 1)-1) AS A_NAME
from DUAL;
```

Examples I have been trying for BB side:-

FAILS:

```
select SUBSTR('AA-aa - WHENEHEH', INSTR('AA-aa - WHENEHEH',' - ', -1, 1)+1, 100)
 B_NAME from dual;
```

thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

If your seperator is sure gona be a "space on either side of a hypen"

Then you can use CHR() function.

From your try

```
select substr('AA-aa - BB-bb', 0,instr('AA-aa - BB-bb', ' - ', 1, 1)-1) AS A_NAME
from DUAL;
```

Use something like this

```
select substr('AA-aa - BB-bb',0,instr('AA-aa - BB-bb',chr(32))-1) from dual; /* ASCII value for space is chr(32) /*
```

### O/P

AA-aa

```
select substr('AA-aa - BB-bb',instr('AA-aa - BB-bb',chr(32))+2,10) from dual;
```

### O/P

" - BB"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, as shown in your list of scenarios, the pattern '- BB' can be relied on, you can use that to find the split.

```
WITH
DATA AS (
  SELECT 'BB' text FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AA - BB' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AA-aa - BB' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AA - BB-bb-cc' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AA-aa - BB-bb-cc' FROM dual
  ),
break AS (
  SELECT text, instr(text, '- BB') breakpos  FROM DATA
)
SELECT
  text,
  CASE WHEN breakpos = 0 THEN NULL ELSE substr( text, 1, breakpos-1 ) END aa_side,
  case when breakpos = 0 then text else substr( text, breakpos+2) end bb_side
FROM break
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition of a single value show up in second column instead of first is a bit odd, but this should do everything else you require:

```
with testdata as (
select 'BB'  as input_col, 1 as row_num from dual
union
select 'AA - BB', 2 from dual
union
select 'AA-aa - BB',3 from dual
)
select testdata.row_num,
case when (regexp_instr(testdata.input_col,'(\ -\ )') > 0) then
  regexp_replace(testdata.input_col, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\1')
else null
end output_col1,
regexp_replace(testdata.input_col, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') as output_col2
from testdata
order by testdata.row_num;
```

Edit: I modified the above to add the case check.  I admit there is probably a more eloquent way to do this via the regexp_replace itself, but this works too.

Comment: It looks like I would need to know every possible combination within the data and code that in - I will not know that data detail.<br>I am reading thousands of rows from table A and inserting specific columns into table B, where tableA.columnC has the concatenation (hyphen) I want to insert tableA.columnC (A side) into tableB.columnC and tableA.columnC (B side) into tableB.columnD - so the extarction code cannot be too complex or degrade performance.

Comment: @user2008555 i dont understand. "every possible combination" of what?  If you know your delimiter (" - " in this case) then the above will work.  If the testdata part confuses you, this is just to show how the output would look, the regexp_replace lines are doing the actual work.  If you need to insert into 2 different tables (output_col1=>table1, output_col2=>table2) then just run 2 input statements (each using 1 of the 2 regexp statements above)

Comment: OK, I see where you are coming from and the above does work except for one scenario where I think I first need to check that the " - " exists befor applying the twp regexp_replace statements. Like I say most of the rows have concatenated data in column.A and for those situations the two regexp_replace statements work, where column.A does not contain " - " I need something like this I think (psuedo code)

Comment: if (column.A contains " - "){
 select regexp_replace('AAA - BB', '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\1') AS A_NAME from dual;
 select regexp_replace('AAA - BB', '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') AS B_NAME from dual;
}
else{
 A_NAME = 'null'
 B_NAME = column.A
}

Comment: I am trying this but it is not working (assume tableA.a = 'aa - bb)
 
Select
if regexp_like(A.a, '[ - ]') then
 regexp_replace(A.a, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\1') AS A_NAME,
 regexp_replace(A.a, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') AS B_NAME,
else
 regexp_replace(A.a, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') AS B_NAME,
end if
FROM table A

Any help is appreciated.

Mark.

Comment: Can anyone help me to fix my remaing issue. I need to wrap a REGEXP_LIKE around the above solution to nitially test for the presence of the delimitter, I am having trouble getting the sytanxe correct - this is what I am trying to achieve in the psuedo code below.

Comment: SELECT TABLE_DATA.COL1 AS COLUMN1, TABLE_DATA.COL2 AS COLUMN2, IF REGEXP_LIKE(TABLE_DATA.COL3, ' - ') THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_DATA.COL3, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\1') AS COL3_FIRST_BIT, REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_DATA.COL3, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') AS COL3_SECOND_BIT, ELSE 'NULL' AS COL3_FIRST_BIT, --WHICH WILL CBE BULL WHEN THERE IS NO ' - ' IN TABLE_DATA.COL3 REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_DATA.COL3, '(.*)(\ -\ )(.*)$', '\3') AS COL3_SECOND_BIT, --WHICH WILL CONTAIN THE WHOLE STRING WHEN THERE IS NO ' - ' IN TABLE_DATA.COL3 END IF TABLE_DATA.COL2 AS COLUMN4, TABLE_DATA.COL2 AS COLUMN5, FROM TABLE_DATA;

Comment: give me a sec, I'll add a case in there and update for u.  I think the condition can be done in the regex itself, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you or someone else ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I think will work for you. (I hope I understood your requirement right)
I tried the query with all the examples you had mentioned and it works good.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('AA-aa - BB-bb-cc',
                  '[^ - ]+')
      "Right Side",
   SUBSTR ('AA-aa - BB-bb-cc',
             INSTR ('AA-aa - BB-bb-cc',
                    ' - ')
           + 2)
      "Left Side"
  FROM DUAL;
```

This one works for everything but for BB and as a work around for that you can check if the delimiter exist and if it doesn't you can take the entire value for the right side.

```
SELECT    SUBSTR ('AA aa - BB',0,
           INSTR ('AA aa - BB',
                ' - ')
          )
    "Right Side",
SUBSTR('AA aa - BB',INSTR('AA aa - BB',
                  ' - ')+2)
      "Left Side"
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Apologies I may not have detailed this situation but the above does not work for 'AA aa - BB' nor does it for 'BB' where I would like BB on the Right side and null to the Left.